# Running leaks on iOS app throws "Cannot allocate mmap" error

Tags: ios, ios5, memory-leaks

I have created an iOS app and need to check the leaks in the app programmatically. 
(Hence not using instruments directly)

For the above I use the leaks command as follows:

MallocStackLogging=1 leaks  -nocontext

At one point of time this was working properly without issues. But recently I have started getting errors and the leaks commands gives different number of leaks each time.

Has anyone faced a similar issue?

Comment: Some useful tips: http://cocoadev.com/wiki/MemoryLeaks

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically find the current memory stats using vm_statics object. Go through these links to find an implementation of vm_statistics:

1)

> http://gamesfromwithin.com/whered-that-memory-go

2)

> http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/iphone/Determining_Available_Memory.20081203.html